# Talend : Use tBufferInput/Output as lookup between subjobs

Tags: talend

Is it possible to use tBufferInput/Output as lookup (with tmap) but in different subjobs and using OnSubJobOK Link ?

In one single job it's simple.

But when I try to retrieve values from my tBufferInput in **Job1** (After running a job writing data in tBufferOutput in **Job2** ) the buffer seems to be empty.

JOB 1 :

[image]

JOB2 :

[image]

My Sequence :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a cache filled in Job1 to read it in Job2. Caches (tBuffers , tHashs) are only available within the same job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cache to propagate data from child to parent Job:

https://help.talend.com/reader/wDRBNUuxk629sNcI0dNYaA/1I5EGN1E92B_kquoxHqV1Q (Scenario 3)

To my knowledge, reverse is not possible.